# Property of a Borel sigma-field

Tags: measure-theory

It is probably not a hard question because in every book, they said it is 'obvious'.

Let $D$ be a metric space and $C_b(D)$ the set of all bounded and continous maps $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Define on $D$ and on $R$ the Borel $\sigma$ field (also known as the Borel $\sigma$ algebra) (Call it $D1$ and $R$). We have the following lemma in which I have a question: The Borel $\sigma$-field on a metric space $D$ is the smallest $\sigma$-field making alll elements of $C_b(D)$ measurable.

So we need to prove that $\sigma (F | F \mbox{ closed} ) = \sigma (F | \exists f \in C_b(D), \exists G \in R: f^{-1}(G) = F )$
the problem is in $\supset$. If we take an element $X$ in $R$ how we can determine if $f^{-1}(X)$ is in $\sigma (F | F \mbox{ closed} )$? If $X$ is closed then it's clear for me, but if it doesn't , how can we prove that $f^{-1}(X) \in \sigma (F | F \mbox{ closed} ) $?